# "Resolvido" Espaçamento entre texto na tabela HTML

Tags: html, table

Boa tarde,
Estou utilizando html com bootstrap 5.0 e estou com uma duvida em reduzir o espaço entre o texto dentro da "td", conforme eu aumento o size da fonte, este espaço aumenta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center" class="bg-success text-white">
    <class style="font-size:510px"><b>612</b><class style="font-size:50px">Portas
  </td>
```

Comment: não entendi, voce quer aumentar o tamanho do seu text sem aumentar o tamanho do seu td ?

Comment: olá renan, se está usando `bootstrap`, pq não utiliza o sistema de grid (row/cols) para fazer esse layout? pelo que notei, está usando table para fazer um layout que não é de tabela, não está fazendo bom uso do potencial do bootstrap :)

Comment: Boa tarde Ricando, legal, sou novo na programação web kkk, boa idéia, vou utilizar o grid. Grato!

Comment: muda o lineheight q resolve

Comment: Richard Gomes, quase isso, na verdade quero remover este espaço e deixar "colado" o 612 portas logo abaixo da linha.

Comment: Coloca margim:0 no título, e só para garantir coloca line-height:1 tb. E cara isso aqui não existe!! `<class style="font-size:510px">`... que tab html é essa ?

Comment: hugocsl, exato, me equivoquei ao escrever o codigo! Abrass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc pode editar o `line-height`

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center" class="bg-success text-white">
    <class style="line-height:350px;font-size:510px"><b>612</b><class style="font-size:50px">Portas
  </td>
 </tr>
```

com isso vc força a linha q ter um tamanho específico.

Comment: Obrigado Jasar, deu certinho, exatamente o que precisava!

Comment: de boa que bom que ajudou. marca como resolvido no meu post assim pessoal sabe q resolveu